# Position absolute and floating divs inside a container

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm having trouble with positioning 3 divs (app-block) absolute within a bigger container with a certain width (775px in this case). The divs float left, but I want them to be absolute so that they don't move on smaller screens.

Css:

```
.app-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:775px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.app-block { width:33.3%; float:left; }
```

Comment: Could you make a JsFiddle with three divs that represent the current problem? Or maybe give us a picture of what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

To position a div absolute, it is ncecesary to give its parent div position property as relative.
Modify the css as below:

```
.app-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:775px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative; 
}

.app-block { width:33.3%; position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 0px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, there are 3 divs to be positioned.